# Trying to make a fairly simple vending machine program, keep getting this error and im not sure at all how to fix this

Tags: python

any help would be appreciated on why this is happening, the program is a fairly basic vending machine. any help at all would be hugely appreciated.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rhsK.png)

i'm not too sure on how to fix this at all, i have only managed to get this far [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1NCL.png)

Comment: Hi George! You mentioned that you get an error but there are none in the image you attached. Please add the error details so that it's easier for us to help you. Posting the full code as text is also always helpful. You can format text as code by putting the backtick symbols around it. Like this: `print("Hello world!")` is equivalent to \`print("Hello world!")\`

Comment: `coin` vs `coins` - typo

Comment: @OlegBezr i have just added the error to the picture!

Comment: You're missing a bracket - it should be `coin = float(input("enter coin: ( "))`. Add one bracket to the right side

Comment: Please don't post images without posting the code as text.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.